# Does cvs2git migrates the Attic folder and the ,v files underneath it to GIT

Tags: cvs2git

I am trying to migrate a cvs repo to GIT which has lot of Attic folders and ,v underneath it. How does the cvs2git preserve this removed files to the git repository for future requirements.

Answer (score 1):

CVS uses the Attic to track deleted files. When I used cvs2git (version 2.3) it migrated all those deleted files and put their contents in the new git repo.  Of course because the files were deleted, they don't appear in a cloned working copy. Do this to view the log of commits for a deleted file in your working copy cloned from the newly created git repo, which will help you get the file back if you need it:

```
git log -- path/to/file.py
```

Hopefully your Attics are in good shape, but if not this SO post discusses corrupt CVS issues - when a file is present *and* also in the Attic, a situation that should never happen:

[CVS comma-v files in Attic and directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420741/cvs-comma-v-files-in-attic-and-directory)

Also see this SO post about recovering files from git:

[Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository)